# Getting eror " The type initializer for 'java.util.Locale' threw an exception." on Report.Init() method of windward

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, windward

I am looking for windward report with .net core.I found some sample on goggle which works fine with .net application but when I tried to create windward report through .net core it gives me error. any suggestion or

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Initialize the engine. License and configuration settings in web.config.
            Configuration.GetSection("Windwardlicense");
            Report.Init();//getting error on this line
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0aDh.png)

Comment: Checking the `windward`, it may not supported in .net core. You may consult the windware developer.

Comment: @TaoZhou I consult them they mention that you can use windward restful engine with .net core but I am not able to add license of windward in .net core.Windward rewstful engine packages need license.How I can add license in .net core? any help is much appericated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windward products don't yet support .NET Core, but you can use our RESTful engine which has to be hosted on a Windows Server running IIS and it will answer POSTs and GETs from your .NET Core application.

If you have more questions, please contact Windward Support at support@windwardstudios.com.